# Customize react-color's SketchPicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-color

I'm using [react-color](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-color)'s SketchPicker and I only want to keep the section where I can pick the colors as the below image shows

[image]

I'm currently using these styles

```
pickerStyles = {
        default: {
            picker: {
                width: "150px",
                height: "200px",
                padding: "0",
                borderRadius: "0",
            }
        }
    };
```

```
<SketchPicker color="#FFFFFF" styles={this.pickerStyles} />
```

how can I add a `display: none` to the below elements of the color picker ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [their docs](https://casesandberg.github.io/react-color/) you can add the following props to hide the opacity slider and the predefined colors suggestions:

```
<SketchPicker
    presetColors={[]}
    disableAlpha
    [...]
/>
```